# Как автоматически перезаписать файл на сервере при его изменении на локальной машине?

Tags: файлы, google-chrome, ftp

Подскажите программу, которая бы могла связываться по FTP с сервером, отслеживала изменения в файле на локальном компьютере и автоматически перезаписывала соответствующий на сервере?

Работаю в панели разработчика Google Chrome, все устраивает, интерфейс удобный, тут же можно редактировать код, удобно что изменения видны сразу, но вот только весь код сохраняется на компьютере, может быть есть программа которая бы синхронизировала файлы на ПК с файлами на сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать самому. Простейший способ, как мне видится: FTP-компонент и таймер, отслеживающий изменение файла (+ открыт или нет файл, зависит от желания). Правда, как показывает практика, затем появляется желание чуть улучшить программу, она обрастает функционалом и т.п. :)

Но если лень, воспользуемся старым добрым [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/):

Скачиваем, ставим (если ещё нет на компе), запускаем, устанавливаем соединение. Затем, не рассоединяясь, идём в меню `Команды/Синхронизация`, выбираем опции, что нам нужны, жмём Ok.

А вот как будет выглядеть примерный текстовый файл настроек:

```
option batch on option confirm off

# open ftp connection open ftp://user:pass@ftpserver

# synchronize files from server synchronize -criteria=size -transfer=binary local C:\vicont\new_project\ /home/vicont/

exit
```

Думаю, понятно, какие параметры вы должны поменять. Теперь создадим командный файл:

```
C:\путь_до_места_где_установлена\WinSCP.exe» /console /script=C:\путь_до_файла_настроек\сам_файл_настроек.txt
```

Теперь остаётся лишь засунуть данный командный файл в планировщик.

Но, согласитесь, идея о собственном синхронизаторе всё же греет душу больше? :)

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто: берём программулину WebDrive, монтируем с её помощью новый диск в винде с папкой сайта сервера и далее в ресурсах консоли разработчика Google Chrome монтируем эту папку. И другими средствами примонтированную в винде папку консоль не видела. Теперь можно прямо в хроме сайты править, красота. Конечно, есть незначительный лаг по перезаписи файлов по фтп, но он ну минимальный.